# PHP commandline: getopt always returns false

Tags: php, command-line, getopt

I am trying to pass some arguments to a simple PHP script on the command line. The script uses `getopt` to read the arguments. However the method always returns `false`, no matter what arguments I specify. According to the docs this indicates an error. But how do I find out what the problem is?

```
<?php
$options = getopt("x");

if ($options === false) 
    echo "No result";
else
    var_dump($options);
?>

// Commandline
$ php myscript.php -x
$ No result
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried all sorts of other arguments specifications in `getopt(...)` but the result is always the same: only `false` is returned.

Any idea?

Comment: When I run your script exactly as  you have it, I get `array(1) { 'x' => bool(false) }`, so the `-x` option is parsed. Is this your real code?

Comment: Yes, this is real code. Is it possible that getopt is disabled somehow? I am running the script on a shared hosting server and I cannot control the PHP config directly.

Comment: BTW: I am using PHP 5.5.14 if this makes any difference

Comment: If `getopt()` was disabled I would expect a fatal error from attempting to call an undefined function. It is possible to disable functions in php.ini, and shared hosts sometimes do so. This is strange. Can you run the same script successfully on a local PHP?

Comment: Yes, on my local OS X machine the exact same script works as expected and shows the same output you mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: I can only suggest you contact your hosts's support to find out if they have disabled the function. You do obviously have basic CLI support - otherwise you couldn't do `php` on the command line to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the option name and if it is required or not (using `:` for required and `::` for an optional arguments.

```
<?php
$options = getopt("x:");

if ($options == false) 
    echo "No result";
else
    var_dump($options);
```

Comment: Omitting `:` or `::` creates a optional boolean that takes no value.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You are correct with this one, it's weird that his code doesn't work as expected

Comment: It would be helpful if this had an example of the command line to show how to get true and false.

Answer (score 1):

The reason, why `getopt` always returned `false` on my machine was:

`register_argc_argv=Off`

the comment says:

> This directive determines whether PHP registers $argv & $argc each
>   time it runs. $argv contains an array of all the arguments passed to
>   PHP when a script is invoked. $argc contains an integer representing
>   the number of arguments that were passed when the script was invoked.
>   These arrays are extremely useful when running scripts from the
>   command line. When this directive is enabled, registering these
>   variables consumes CPU cycles and memory each time a script is
>   executed. For performance reasons, this feature should be disabled on
>   production servers.

and, finally:

> **Note: This directive is hardcoded to On for the CLI SAPI**

but I actually used `php-cli`, so.. it could be a bug (I have PHP 7.2.13). Try enabling `register_argc_argv=On` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The option appears to always have the value of false assigned to it by default.
When the option is not specified at all it simply doesn't exist.

try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$getopt = getopt('x');
if (isset($getopt['x'])){
    echo "The x option was specified and is default value is: ";
    var_dump($getopt['x']);
    exit(0);
} else {
    echo "No valid options were specified\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

`php myscript.php -x` will output:

`The x option was specified and is default value is: bool(false)`

This confused me also hence I ended up here searching for why it does this.